# Self-Hosted Integration Runtime could not connect to Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create a Self-Hosted Integration Runtime for my Azure Data Factory.
I was able to install the Integration Runtime successfully but I'm getting an error registering it:

[image]

I looked at the event log and it says "unable to connect to remote server"

[image]

I've been going around this for days already and can't still find a solution.
any help is highly appreciated :)

Thanks,

Kim

Answer (score 3):

have you opened all the ports as required?:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime#ports-and-firewalls

It looks very likely that thats your issue here.

Comment: This is the most likely cause.